# OpenCV: grabcut.cpp error

Tags: c++, opencv, error-handling, bug-tracking

I am testing "grabcut.cpp" in OpenCV, but while compiling I got the following error message:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed <dtrm> std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon<>> in unknown function, file grabcut.cpp, line 216
```

That line in the file is like this:

```
CV_Assert( dtrm > std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() );
```

Is this a bug? How can I solve it? Thank you.

Comment: Can you paste your code so we can try to compile it on our side? Also, which version of OpenCV are you using (and which platform)?

Comment: I am using the "grabcut.cpp" that is provided by OpenCV itself, and my platform is VC2010 and OpenCV 2.4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a bug that was actually [closed](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/1046) over one year ago. But when checking the actual 2.4.2 release i can see that the patch did not made it into the release. I don't know why but however you can turn off the assertions by just recompile OpenCV with NDEBUG as define. With Visual Studio adding /DNDEBUG to the command line should do the trick.